# Getting rid of extra qubits without changing phase

Tags: quantum-state, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

If I have the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}|0000\rangle + \frac{e^{i\phi}}{\sqrt2}|1111\rangle$
and need to get $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}|0\rangle + \frac{e^{i\phi}}{\sqrt2}|1\rangle$, does anyone have any ideas about how I might go about getting the state?

My first thought was to measure the last three qubits, but I don't think that's correct as I believe it would cause the first qubit to collapse to $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$ due to entanglement.